# Show multiple plots with single variable

Tags: plotting

Using the same example code as in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36726/speed-up-manipulate-by-exporting-each-step-as-an-image), is it possible to show all 10 plots (ie, each step of the manipulation) simultaneously?

If a manipulate function is a series of listplots based on a single variable, is it possible to show all list plots simultaneously (ie - to overlay all listplots as one static plot).

The only way I can think of doing this is copying & pasting the code n number of times, changing the variable for each one, naming each listplot & using

```
Show [a,b,c,d...]
```

but this seems fairly labour intensive!

Comment: Can you post sample code so we have a better idea of what the problem is?

Comment: You can show multiple sets of data in a single plot: "[`ListPlot[{list1, list2, ...}]` plots several lists of points.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot.html)" Is that what you want?

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid it's still not clear.  The question above says "Using the same example code" but in a comment to an answer below you said you want to use functions instead of data.  Generally speaking, `ListPlot` is for data and `Plot` is for functions, and you speak consistently of "listplot."  The answer below seems on target, so I must not be getting what it is that you're after.  Could you clarify further?  Also, when possible it is better for questions to be self-contained.  You could put example code into this question without making it much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create your plots (pay attention to the maximum plot range and the same image dimensions) with

```
plots = ListPlot[
 pdata = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/12.34], {x, #}] + 
   RandomReal[.1, {#}], PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, ImageSize -> {500, 200}] & /@Table[i, {i, 100, 200, 10}];
```

display them individually with

```
Manipulate[plots[[n]], {n, 1, Length[plots], 1}]
```

and show them all at once with

```
Show[plots]
```

Comment: @ Kardashev3, Thank you for your reply, but I am working with functions rather than data (see update of question above). - Sorry, I should have been clearer about this initially.

Comment: @ martin: I have altered my answer to your needs, does ist work for you now?