# Speed up manipulate by exporting each step as an image

Tags: export, manipulate, slideshows

Consider a manipulate function such as:

```
Manipulate[
per = 12.34;
pdata = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/per], {x, n}] + RandomReal[.1, {n}];
ListPlot[pdata], {n, 100, 200, 10}]
```

which takes some time to re-evaluate each step of its manipulation. I would like to export each step of the manipulation as an image (rasterized or otherwise) & then create a manipulation that simply scrolls though the images, allowing it to run smoothly and quickly. Is there a way to automate something like this?

*(NB The code I am working with takes far longer to re-evaluate each step that the example code above, but it works with much the same idea.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the images with

```
images = Image[
 ListPlot[
  pdata = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/12.34], {x, #}] + 
    RandomReal[.1, {#}]]] & /@ Table[i, {i, 100, 200, 10}];
```

and show them with

```
Manipulate[images[[n]], {n, 1, Length[images], 1}]
```

then you can export them with

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "image" <> ToString[#] <> ".tif", Image[images[[#]]]] & /@ Range[Length[images]]
```

later on (i.e. in another notebook residing in the same directory) you simply load the images into a list and view them with

```
Manipulate[images[[n]], {n, 1, Length[images], 1}]
```

Comment: @ Kardashev3, again, many thanks - but please see update.

Comment: @ Kardashev3, Great! Many thanks - I will now try to implement it in the code I am working with (... could be a long time!) :)

Comment: @ Kardashev3, Many thanks for your update - I was about to ask you about exporting them!

Comment: @ Kardashev3, I suppose this answers my other question also, as it should be fairly straightforward to use Show to overlay all exported images (if exported in eps, pdf format,etc.):)

Comment: @martin: You have to produce plots with the same plot range (in your example the maximum plot range of 200) in order to correctly show all points altogether. I have updated my answer with the respective options, see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36725/show-multiple-plots-with-single-variable.

Answer (score 3):

In this case [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/731) can be used. It can often be used for cases like this.

```
pdata[n_, per_] := pdata[n, per] = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/per], {x, n}] + RandomReal[.1, {n}];
```

Makes sure `pdata` never performs the same calculation twice. If we calculate all relevant values in advance,

```
Do[pdata[n, 12.34], {n, 100, 200, 10}]
```

They will already be stored when you run `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 per = 12.34;
 ListPlot[pdata[n, per]], {n, 100, 200, 10}]
```

Comment: @ Anon, Thanks for your answer - I will try out both approaches & see which is most efficient ;)

Comment: @martin If you want to see it used to improve speed in a manipulate with somewhat heavy calculations, you may want to take a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34857/731

Comment: @ Anon, Wow! That is quick! My only worry is that Mathematica would have to go through the evaluation process every time the file is reopened - could this be avoided? Or is it better to export all images?

Comment: @ Anon, Perhaps I am missing the point - I will have to experiment with it to understand more fully what  you mean, I think...

Comment: I am getting an error message: SetDelayed::write: Tag List in <<1>> is Protected. >> after 'Do'

Comment: @martin Execute `Clear[pdata]` before the definition of `pdata[n_, per_] := ...`.  Your old `pdata` definition is probably hanging around.

Comment: @Michael E2 - thanks - keep forgetting to do that!

Comment: @martin I think it can be avoided by saving the symbol with `DumpSave` but it would practically be the same as Michael's solution. If you need to be able to restart the kernel in between, perhaps his answer is the most suitable.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to saving images is to save the graphics themselves with [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DumpSave.html).

```
per = 12.34;
myPlots = 
 Table[ListPlot[Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/per], {x, i}] + RandomReal[.1, {i}]],
       {i, 100, 200, 10}];
DumpSave[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo.mx"}], myPlots];

Manipulate[
 Show[myPlots[[i]], Framed -> True],
 {i, 1, Dynamic @ Length @ myPlots, 1},
 Initialization :> (Get[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "foo.mx"}]])]
```

One can alter the options to the `Graphics`, such as adding a frame, and interact with the output as `Graphics`.  This can't be done with images, at least in the same way.

---

Another alternative that is more self-contained is below.  It auto-generates the plots and the .mx file if the file is missing.  Of course that takes time, but the notebook file containing the `Manipulate` can be sent alone and the `Manipulate` output can be copied and pasted into another notebook, which might be in a different directory or in no directory at all.  This means that the notebook can be shared with or without the accompanying .mx file.

If there is no .mx file, then the `Manipulate` pauses while all the plots are generated.  This is accomplished by the combination of

```
SynchronousInitialization -> False,
```

and the line in the `Initialization`:

```
`Do[plot[nn], {nn, 100, 200, 10}]`
```

(This line may be omitted, but there will be a wait each time a plot is displayed for the first time.  Once all the plots have been generated, the `Manipulate` will operate smoothly.)

The plots are generated and stored via memoization, as in [Anon's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/anon) answer, and the definitions create are save by `DumpSave` in the `Deinitialization`.  It's not absolutely foolproof, e.g. *Mathematica* crashes, or a user executes `Clear[plot]`.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[plot[n], Frame -> True],

 {n, 100, 200, 10}, {directory, None},

 SynchronousInitialization -> False,
 Initialization :> (
   directory = Quiet@Check[NotebookDirectory[], $TemporaryDirectory];
   per = 12.34;
   Quiet@Get[FileNameJoin[{directory, "foo2.mx"}]];
    (* this would have been loaded from the .mx ... unless there's no .mx file *)
   plot[n_] := plot[n] = 
      ListPlot[Pause[0.5]; Table[Sin[2 Pi x/per], {x, n}] + RandomReal[.1, {n}]];
    (* fast if plot is loaded from .mx; otherwise predefines all the plots *)
   Do[plot[nn], {nn, 100, 200, 10}]
   ),
 Deinitialization :> DumpSave[FileNameJoin[{directory, "foo2.mx"}], plot]
 ]
```