# Export vector images

Tags: export, image-processing

I am having difficulties exporting vector graphics. Using Kardashev3's code provided [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36726/speed-up-manipulate-by-exporting-each-step-as-an-image):

```
images = Image[ListPlot[pdata = Table[Sin[2 \[Pi] x/12.34], {x, #}] + 
RandomReal[.1, {#}]]] & /@ Table[i, {i, 100, 200, 10}];
```

and then exporting them as follows:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "image" <> ToString[#] <> ".eps", 
"AllowRasterization" -> False, Image[images[[#]]]] & /@ Range[Length[images]]
Manipulate[images[[n]], {n, 1, Length[images], 1}]
```

I get the error message:

```
<<Export::noelem: {...} is not a valid set of export elements for the EPS format.>>
```

The code works well for rasterized graphics, but appears to run into problems with vector graphics.

Comment: `Image` will represent rasterized graphics, which will not yield vectorized output. You should work with the initial `Graphics` expression returned by `ListPlot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
Export[
 NotebookDirectory[] <> "image" <> ToString[#] <> ".eps", 
 Image[images[[#]]],
 "AllowRasterization" -> False] & /@ Range[Length[images]]
```

**Edit**

I think the OP is asking for this:

```
plots = ListPlot[
     pdata = Table[Sin[2 Pi x/12.34], {x, #}] + 
       RandomReal[.1, {#}]] & /@ Table[i, {i, 100, 200, 10}];
Export["plot" <> ToString[#] <> ".eps", 
    plots[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[plots]]
```

which produces a set of EPS files.

Comment: Still rasterizing the image unfortunately

Comment: Could it be something in the initial Image line?

Comment: I was addressing the error in your `Export` code - I don't think you can de-rasterize an `Image`...

Comment: Obviously! ;) ... Is it possible to export multiple eps/pdf *before* they are rasterized, or would individual files have to be exported separately?

Comment: @martin I didn't ask why you were using all those `Image` commands... :)

Comment: @ cormullion Brilliant! Thanks! *(for not asking also:))*